# How to logout the user when in active if already login?

Tags: reactjs, express

Hi I am developing an application using react and node js.

In the login page of the application i checked the condition of user activity if the user is in active then this  user can't login to the application. But If he already login to the application then i don't know the user activity to logout the user.

I thought a solution to check in every api response if the user is active or not. But I can't check the response of every api.

So How can i do That